# HtmlDecode dont work using Razor MVC inside html attribute with Viewbag and selectlist

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Viewbag with some documents list and one of the document in the list have the name "test1>test2". My html syntax looks like

```
@Html.DropDownList("Documents", (SelectList)ViewBag.Documents, "--Select Document--", new { @class = "selectField" })
```

When it open in browser, the dropdown list the document name "test1>test2" shown as "test2&gttest1"(have semicolan after &gt). How do i show the name exactly like "test1>test2" in place of "test2&gttest1"?

**EDIT:**

When i checked it in detail, the problem is not with my razor syntax,it is with jquery which using to bind my dropdownlist uisng "test1>test2" value. My jquery looks like below.

```
 jq("#Documents" + "> option").remove();
 jq("#Documents").append(jq("<option />").val('@ViewBag.DraftDocId').text('@ViewBag.DraftDocTitle'));
```

here ViewBag.DraftDocTitle is the "test1>test2" value

Comment: Did you `HtmlEncode` it before using? Actually, the `greater than` special character would become `&gt;` as can be [seen here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: @michaelmoore No i did not use HtmlEncode. I checked ViewBag.Documents values before rendering it to the browser. The value was correct at that time. But the value change only occurs after page rendering.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply **HTMLDecode** to encoded string. See below code sample to bind your dropdown list:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Documents", ((SelectList)ViewBag.Documents).Select(i => { i.Text = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(i.Text); return i; }), "--Select Document--", new { @class = "selectField" })
```

**Update: Using JQuery**

```
jq("#Documents" + "> option").remove();
jq("#Documents").append(jq("<option />").val('@ViewBag.DraftDocId').text('@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.DraftDocTitle)'));
```

Comment: i modified the code as you said, but the result looks like same..:(

Comment: can you update your question with your controller code and with data ?

Comment: When i checked it in detail, the problem is not with my razor syntax,it is with jquery which using to bind my dropdownlist uisng "test1>test2" value. My jquery looks like below. How can i use your code within jquery syntax?
  jq("#Documents" + "> option").remove();
            jq("#Documents").append(jq("<option />").val('@ViewBag.DraftDocId').text('@ViewBag.DraftDocTitle'));

here ViewBag.DraftDocTitle is the "test1>test2" value

Comment: using jquery you can use it something like this : `.text('@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(ViewBag.DraftDocTitle)'));`

Comment: @NithinPaul: Have a look at my updated answer. Hope it will help you to solve your problem. Don't forget to upvote and mark it as an answer if it helped you. So that other developer can also refer this answer.

Comment: i checked it with jquery code still the result is same.

Comment: please make sure that there isn't any other utility which encodes this text.

Comment: I checked the answer using alert as follow. But still its not alerting the correct result. Have you tested it before?

alert("Review1" + '@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(@ViewBag.DraftDocTitle)');

Answer (score 0):

please add the codes which creates ViewBag.Documents on controller part to your question. Since i have tried and everything was fine with the following code block,

in controller

```
        List<string> elements = new List<string>();
        elements.Add("test1>test2");
        SelectList selectList = new SelectList(elements);
        ViewBag.Documents = selectList;
```

in view

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Documents", (SelectList)ViewBag.Documents, "--Select Document--", new { @class = "selectField" })
```

probably you are creating elements list by some calculation. There is something wrong in there i think.

Comment: In my controller this is the code i am using ViewBag.Documents = new SelectList(drafts.OrderBy(c => c.Text), "Value", "Text");

here the drafts is a list, i checked its containing values. The values showing is correct.

Comment: In my controller i added your code and checked the result. But still i am getting the same result. Strange...